# unable add multiple jpanel(each jpanel is a separate timer run concurrently) to jframe using arraylist only initial jpanel is getting addeed?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, timer, jpanel

this is code is in jframe class with name"Timer1.java" and jpanel class name is "Timer_UI.java"

```
   ArrayList<Timer_UI> mul_panels = new ArrayList<Timer_UI>();
    public void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    Timer_UI d_timer = new Timer_UI();
           mul_panels.add(d_timer);
           Timer_UI dis_timer = mul_panels.get(i);
           i++;
           dis_timer.setBackground(Color.white);
           dis_timer.setBounds(34, 110, 434, 178);
           add(dis_timer);
           height = height + 230;
           setSize(new Dimension(523,height));
    }
```

the execution of the application

Execution of the application. Only one jpanel object is add on click again there is no timer added to frame:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SxUC.jpg]

Comment: please consider making your title more specific, doubt anyone is going to find the answer to this question through search engines.

Comment: Please show us your best [mcve] attempt so that we can have code that compiles, runs and demonstrates the problem. Please understand that we don't want to see your whole program, especially if it's larger than 60 lines long, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also, you do understand that a JFrame (actually, its contentPane) uses BorderLayout by default, and that if you do not change this, only the last JPanel that has been added (without specifying where) will be shown, right?

Comment: Quit shouting! Bold is used to highlight specific words or phrases, not the entire text of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setBounds() to set the size of your components.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

If you want to add more timer panels horizontally then you need to use an appropriate layout manager. Maybe a `BoxLayout`, or a `GridLayout`.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more information and working examples

So the basic logic might be something like:

```
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout());
topPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
topPanel.add(button1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
topPanel.add(button2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

Box timerPanel = new Box.createVerticalBox();

frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(timerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now when you want to create a new timer the ActionListner code would be something like:

```
Timer_UI dis_timer = mul_panels.get(i);
dis_timer.setMaximumSize( dis_timer.getPreferredSize() );
timerPanel.add( dis_timer );
timerPanel.revalidate();
timerPanel.repaint();
```